# Parsed multiline TextBox string contains unwanted line breaks characters

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to parse an address out of a multi-line text box, like this:

[image]

I need to get each line into a unique string inside a `List(Of String)`, and remove the separator characters the user has entered (`","`).  Pretty easy using:

```
Dim a As String = txt.Text.Trim.Replace(",", String.Empty)
Dim l As List(Of String) = a.Split(Environment.NewLine).ToList()
For Each s As String In l
    Trace.Warn(String.Format("Parsed {0}: {1}", l.IndexOf(s).ToString, s))
Next
```

On examining the trace output however, there are additional line breaks that still exist.  The debugger also shows their existence:

[image]

I assume this is because `Environment.NewLine` is not the correct choice for the separator.  If so, **why?** - it clearly is a new line!

What is actually happening here under the hood, and what's the correct solution?

**UPDATE**

Comparing the contents of the string to the CHR(n) equivalent representation, the following output reveals what's *actually* contained in the box, `Chr(10)` plus `Chr(13)`:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the output for `txt`. Does it contain line feeds `\n` and/or carriage returns `\r`?

Comment: Question updated with findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Chr(10)` and `Chr(13)` behave independently of one another.  The solution was to `Split` using `Environment.NewLine` and then iterate the list and manually removing the remaining `Chr(10)` characters that remained.

```
Dim a As String = txt.Text.Trim.Replace(",", String.Empty)
Dim l As List(Of String) = a.Split(Environment.NewLine).ToList()
For i As Integer = 0 To l.Count - 1
    l(i) = l(i).Replace(Chr(10), String.Empty)
Next
```